# Bind GridView with table from sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview, data-binding

i want to bind my grid view with a table from sql server but not getting a proper solution to this.
share with me how its done
My application is a test application

Comment: Welcome to SO sam!  Post what you've tried so far as well as errors you've received and it will be a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

private string ConnectionString { get; set; } //Bind Your Connection String

private SqlCommand cmd;

private SqlConnection con;

private DataSet ds;

DataSet GetTableData()
    {

```
    try

    {

        using (con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 

        {

            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from <table-name> ", con);

            ds = new DataSet();


            var data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            data.Fill(ds);

        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        //Error Logic

    }

    return ds;

}
```

Once you get Values returned from abovefunction , bind to gridview

[GridviewID].dataSource= GetTableData();

[GridviewID].dataBind();